# Git: Is it considered bad practice to change git log's history by force pushing?

Tags: git

I've had an argue with my boss about working with Git approach.

I wrote a Jenkins pipeline which polls SCM every 5 minutes and triggers a build if there was a push to the relevant branch.

In order to test it, I've created a new branch called itai_test, checked out into it, created a new file called itai.txt, commited and pushed.

The test went properly... Jenkins polled SCM, identified the change and triggered a build... just as expected.

When I decided that I'm happy with the result of the test I've ran `git log`, found the SHA of the last commit before my test commit, reverted to that commit and pushed force the changes into origin.

Now, when I told my boss about it he got pissed and told me to never change the history of git... that it is something nobody does.

So for example I asked him what he thinks about squashing and he said the same... "It is not the right way to work".

I think that it is a matter of approach and not a right or wrong thing to do but I'm not as experienced with Git as my boss.

So can you please share your approach?

Comment: As it stands, this question is asking for opinions, which is not a good fit for SO. The only thing that can be given as a fact is that "that it is something nobody does" is factually incorrect. There are certainly people who do force push sometimes.

Comment: If you have not pushed to a remote, then you can change history and squash commits all you want with no one the wiser. Once you've pushed, you can start causing problems or headaches for others.

Comment: A principle is that do not change the log history if it has been published to others unless you can make sure everyone of them finds it okay. Sometimes you youself is one of the others because you may have different clones and may regret.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagine these two scenarios. They are meant to be exaggerations in order to get the point across.

- Your SW has gone out to the customers. Bug reports come in. You try to reproduce the problem but cannot. Then one of your colleagues says "Oh, the version 1.3 that we have in the repo might not be the same as the version as the customer has because we've changed some commits after the fact. The SW that the customers have as v1.3 might be different from the v1.3 in our repo." Whaaat?!?
- Your SW has gone out to the customers. It turns out that there is actually some malware in the software; this is provable. Yet when you look at your source code, you find no evidence of commits including the malware. It seems as if whoever put the malware in has erased those commits and hidden their tracks. You apparently have no traceability/auditability of your code.

These are just two small examples of why *generally*, source code eventually has one canonical final repository and it is *append only* and you cannot rewrite history.

(This was just common sense "back in the day". With DVCS these days, there may be some "religious" disagreement about this, and I don't think we need to get into that... others who disagree can just present their cases politely.)

However, if this is something important at your company, it should not be left to a "you shouldn't do that" optional rule. It should be enforced on the git server-side so that it is simply not possible.